# How to save only few columns to cassandra using spark In Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to save a RDD to Cassandra using

```
JavaRDD<UserSetGet> rddFromGz = sc.parallelize(ListFromS3);

CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(rddFromGz)
        .writerBuilder("dmp", "table", mapToRow(UserSetGet.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

Here UserSetGet object has all the fields Initialized.

But I  wish to save some columns only , how to do that ?

In the doc , it says we can do

```
.saveToCassandra("test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "1"));
```

But it is not recognising SomeColumns Method.

Answer (score 1):

The SomeColumns method is for the **Scala** api, you're using the Java API...

Maybe it's a good opportunity to switch to Scala

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer , but as of now I cant switch to scala API , so is there anyway I could achieve the same in Java ?

Comment: I guess there is some way to call Scala code from Java but it's very hacky ... good luck

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below lines will help you

```
val w1 = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(rdd23).writerBuilder("smart","emp", CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(classOf[emp]))
w1.withColumnSelector(CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns("pid","page")).saveToCassandra()
```